# Scrolling X and Y panes at the same time in codenameone

Tags: java, scroll, codenameone

I have a scrollable-Y container that contains some components alongside a scrollable-X container.

When I'm scrolling up or down and get to scrollable-X container, I can't scroll it left or right until the up and down scrolling comes to rest. The same thing happens vice-versa.

How do I make both containers be scrollable at the same time? If I'm scrolling up and my thumb lay on the Scrollable-X container, I want to be able to scroll it too without stopping or waiting for Scrollable-Y container to stop.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a specific lock there to prevent that from happening because otherwise the move becomes a bit too "jerky".

Currently there is a strong assumption in Codename One that only one component is being scrolled at a time so when we handle the pointer drag events we make a choice based on the movement bias. If you want to see the very dirty and complex decision tree check out `Component.pointerDragged` but be warned its not pretty...

You might be able to hack something by detecting this specific use case when overriding pointer dragged.